# Change maker with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to make a change maker with a for loop so it tells me how much coins (quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies) it takes to get to the inputted amount.

Here is my code so far:

```
amount = input("Enter the amount of change owed: ")
amount = int(amount)

coins = [25, 10, 5, 1]

for coin in coins:
```

I'm not exactly sure how to iterate through the list and have it tell me how much of each coin would be in the inputted amount.

For example, it would probably look something like this:

```
Enter the amount of change owed: 99
Quarters: 3
Dimes: 9
Nickels: 19
Pennies: 99
```

Sorry for the stupid question, I'm still getting used to python.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking you example as what you want your code to do, all you need is a simple division :

```
amount = input("Enter the amount of change owed: ")
amount = int(amount)

coins = [25, 10, 5, 1]
results = []

for coin in coins:
    results.append(amount // coin) # The // sign is used to avoid fractions

print("Quarters: {}".format(results[0]))
print("Dimes: {}".format(results[1]))
print("Nickels: {}".format(results[2]))
print("Pennies: {}".format(results[3]))
```

The idea of the `for coin in coins` is that in the first loop, the value of **coin** is 25, then 10, then 5, then 1.
All you need to do then is to store the required coins in a list, and output them later

If you want you code to print how to make the change, all you need to do is subtract the value of the previous coin like so :

```
for coin in coins:
    coin_nb = amount / coin
    results.append(coin_nb)
    amount -= coin * coin_nb # We substract the change we already gave back
```